# Why doesn't my arulezViz plot show labels when the engine is set to htmlwidget

Tags: r, arules

I'm trying to make a graph plot of my rules through arulezViz, however when I set the engine htmlwidget I don't get any labels on the plot.

My code:

```
plot(rules, method = 'graph', engine = 'htmlwidget')
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, this looks like a bug. I have filed a bug report here: https://github.com/mhahsler/arulesViz/issues/21

Comment: The issue is now resolved in arulesViz_1.5-1. Please upgrade to the latest version.